# NHibernate/Hibernate for bitemporal database

Tags: hibernate, nhibernate, temporal-database

Having good success with NHibernate and EF in the past, I'm trying to convince a team member to use Hibernate in a new Java project which uses a bitemporal database schema. However, I have never used NHibernate (or any other ORM) with a bitemporal model before.

Any pitfalls and/or advice of which I should be aware of when using Hibernate/NHibernate with bitemporal database model ?

Thanks!

Comment: I also plan to develop a bitemporal DB with NHibernate. So I'm interessted in how you did it and your lessons learned.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this post](http://blog.lowendahl.net/?p=190) by Patrik Löwendahl, where he talks about tracking property values over time with NHibernate. Probably not exactly what you were looking for, but it's something.

Also, if you wanted to take a recipe out of a Hibernate cookbook, take a look at the DAO Fusion [bitemporal pattern](http://opensource.anasoft.com/daofusion-site/reference/bitemporal-pattern.html%20bitemporal%20pattern%20from%20DAO%20Fusion).